# Python multiprocessing imap without list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've parallelized my code using imap and the pyfastx library but the problem is that the sequences get loaded using a list comprehension. When the input file is large this becomes problematic because all *seq* values are loaded in memory. Is there a way to do this without completely populating the list that's inputted to imap?

```
import pyfastx
import multiprocessing

def pSeq(seq):
...
  return(A1,A2,B)

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(5)
for (A1,A2,B) in
      pool.imap(pSeq,[seq for _,seq,_ in pyfastx.Fastq(temp2.name, build_index=False)],chunksize=100000):
  if A1 == A2 and A1 != B: 
    matchedA[A1][B] += 1
```

I also tried skipping the list comprehension and using the *apply_async* function since pyfastx supports loading the sequences one at a time but because each individual loop is fairly short and there's no *chunksize* argument this ends up taking way longer than just not using multiprocessing at all.

```
import pyfastx
import multiprocessing

def pSeq(seq):
...
  return(A1,A2,B)

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(5)
results = []
for _,seq,_ in pyfastx.Fastq(temp2.name, build_index=False):
  results.append(pool.apply_async(pSeq,seq))
pool.join()
pool.close()

for result in results:
  if result[0] == result[1] and result[0] != result[2]:
    matchedA[result[0]][result[2]] +=1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the original post, but I actually dealt with a similar issue so thought this may be helpful for someone at some point.

First of all, the general solution is to pass imap an iterator or generator object, instead of a list. In this case, you would modify pSeq to accept a tuple of 3 and simply drop the list comprehension.
I am including some code below to demonstrate what I mean, but let me preempt somebody trying this - it doesn't work (at least in my hands). My guess is this happens because, for some reason, pyfastx.Fastq doesn't return an iterator or generator object (I did verify this tidbit - the returned object doesn't implement next)...
I worked around this by using fastq-and-furious, which is comparably fast and does return a generator (and also has a more flexible python API). That workaround code is at the bottom, if you want to skip the "solution that should have worked".
At any rate, here is what I would have liked to work:

```
def pSeq(seq_tuple):
    _, seq, _ = seq_tuple
    ...
    return(A1,A2,B)

...
import multiprocessing as mp
with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
    # this fails (when I ran it on Mac, the program hung and I had to keyboard interrupt)
    # most likely due to pyfastx.Fastq not returning a generator or iterator
    parser = pyfastx.Fastq(temp2.name, build_index=False)
    result_iterator = pool.imap(pSeq, parser, chunksize=100000)
    for result in result_itertor:
        do something
```

Just to make this answer complete, I am also adding my workaround code, which does work for me. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to run properly while still using pyfastx:

```
import fastqandfurious.fastqandfurious as fqf
import fastqandfurious._fastqandfurious as _fqf

# if you don't supply an entry function, fqf returns (name, seq, quality) as byte-strings
def pfx_like_entry(buf, pos, offset=0):
    """
    Return a tuple with identical format to pyfastx, so reads can be 
    processed with the same function regardless of which parser we use
    """
    name = buf[pos[0]:pos[1]].decode('ascii')
    seq = buf[pos[2]:pos[3]].decode('ascii')
    quality = buf[pos[4]:pos[5]].decode('ascii')
    return name, seq, quality

# can be replaced with fqf.automagic_open(), gzip.open(), some other equivalent
with open(temp2.name, mode='rb') as handle, \
        mp.Pool(5) as pool:
    # this does work. You can also use biopython's fastq parsers
    # (or any other parser that returns an iterator/ generator)
    parser = fqf.readfastq_iter(fh=handle,
                                fbufsize=20000,
                                entryfunc=pfx_like_entry
                                _entrypos=_fqf.entrypos
                                )
    result_iterator = pool.imap(pSeq, parser, chunksize=100000)
    for result in result_itertor:
        do something
```